# Getting error 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1', but columns = rows

Tags: php, mysql

As the title suggests I am getting the 'Column count doesn't match value count at row 1' error. After comparing the values I want to send to database with my database and did not find a mistake, I looked over the internet and tried various solutions. None of them worked so far. I also tried to use SET instead of VALUES. Like 'Passwort' = '$passwort' - Also did not do the trick. Here is my code, maybe someone spots an obvious mistake that I missed?

```
 $name = ($_GET["name"]);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table VALUES('$name')";

 $passwort = ($_GET["passwort"]);
 $sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table VALUES('$passwort')";

 $con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die (mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_set_charset('utf8', $con);

 mysql_query("INSERT INTO $DB_Table (Name,Passwort) VALUES ('$name','$passwort')");
 $res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
 mysql_close($con);
if ($res) {
    echo "Der Benutzer wurde neu angelegt!";
}else{
    echo "Der Benutzername ist bereits vergeben";
}
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799). Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you care to learn, [here is a quite good PDO-related tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: start database connection at top of the script, you are assigning `$sql` two times, you are not making basic checks to see if this succeeded, and you still use mysql_* functions.. for me it looks like a bad start on PHP, try reading more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table VALUES('$name')";

$sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table VALUES('$passwort')";
```

Here you just overwritten the previous variable, so what's the point of having the previous one?

And then you're trying to execute the query, which will fail, as the table has more columns.

```
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

I don't even know why you're trying to do this, as the previous line already did the insert. Did you meant to do this? :

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO $DB_Table (Name,Passwort) VALUES ('$name','$passwort')");
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

That all said, your code is vulnerably to SQL injection attacks, and it's using a the old mysql interface.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, a few things you should change. To answer your question, one of your variables is likely empty at the time it is being inserted.

Having said that, your code is WIDE open to injection attacks. Check your variables before putting them into the database. What would you do if I entered my name as "Tom; drop table users;" and your code just ran it?

Answer (score 1):

The obvious mistake is that you insert only one value for a table with at least two columns. In the line

```
$res = mysql_query($sql,$con) or die(mysql_error());
```

$sql contains the string

```
"INSERT INTO $DB_Table VALUES('$passwort')";
```